# byte-compile errors

Tags: emacs, compiler-errors

I want to byte-compile some el files in my .emacs.d directory.I wrote a file like this:
cl.el:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/slime/")
(require 'slime)
```

and someother code.when i byte-compile it,the error is:

```
Error: Cannot open load file: slime
```

however,i really put the slime package in the directory.
and i use the batch-byte-compile also find that all el files contain

```
(require '***)
```

will result out the similar error

Comment: You shouldn't call a file in your loadpath `cl.el` because the CL compatibility package is called `cl`. That might even be the problem because `slime` requires `cl`

Comment: please add debugger message to your question. `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET`.

Comment: @kindahero i don't know how to debug this.and i used the command line to byte-compile(emacs -batch -f batch-byte-compile *.el).however,this time i byte-compile in emacs,no problems occur.

Comment: @MichaelMarkert perhaps not the problem.because many other el files also happens.like muse

Answer (score 1):

~ does not get expanded; use an absolute path, or `(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/slime/"))`.

This is unrelated to byte compilation, per se.

Comment: Recent Emacsen do that expansion transparently, so expand-file-name is no longer required.

Comment: If my answer didn't help, then no, I don't know what is wrong.  Maybe post a backtrace?  @Michael Markert's comment looks promising, though.